# Why this shell command doesn't work? ('command' works but 'command|cat' doesn't work)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ffmpeg, grep

## Problem

The following code outputs like...

```
$ ffprobe -show_frames -select_streams v test.mp4 2>/dev/null|grep -A 2 key_frame=1
key_frame=1
pkt_pts=0
pkt_pts_time=0:00:00.000000
--
key_frame=1
pkt_pts=41041
pkt_pts_time=0:00:01.710042
--
key_frame=1
pkt_pts=64064
pkt_pts_time=0:00:02.669333
--
key_frame=1
pkt_pts=87087
pkt_pts_time=0:00:03.628625
--
...
```

But the folowing one outputs nothing.

```
$ ffprobe -show_frames -select_streams v test.mp4 2>/dev/null|grep -A 2 key_frame=1|cat
```

And...

```
$ ffprobe -show_frames -select_streams v test.mp4 2>/dev/null|grep key_frame=1
key_frame=1
key_frame=1
key_frame=1
key_frame=1
$ ffprobe -show_frames -select_streams v test.mp4 2>/dev/null|grep key_frame=1|cat
# Nothing outputted.
```

Why?

## Expected result

What actually I want to do is

```
$ ffprobe -show_frames -select_streams v test.mp4 2>/dev/null|grep -A 2key_frame=1|grep time
pkt_pts_time=0:00:00.000000
pkt_pts_time=0:00:01.710042
pkt_pts_time=0:00:02.669333
pkt_pts_time=0:00:03.628625
...
```

But its result is

```
$ ffprobe -show_frames -select_streams v test.mp4 2>/dev/null|grep -A 2key_frame=1|grep time
# Nothing outputted.
```

Grep works correctory exept it's after ffprobe.

```
$ seq 30|grep 1|grep 2
12
21
```

## Environment

- Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10 Pro

  - Windows version: 1803
  - Windows OS build: 17134.345

Environment of Ubuntu:

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

$ ffprobe
ffprobe version 3.4.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Simple multimedia streams analyzer
usage: ffprobe [OPTIONS] [INPUT_FILE]

You have to specify one input file.
Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffprobe'.
```

What is problem?

Does grep or ffprobe change its behavior by existence of pipe `in this case`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easier way to reproduce your problem:

```
$ while sleep 1; do date; done | grep ""
Tue Oct 16 14:51:25 PDT 2018
Tue Oct 16 14:51:26 PDT 2018
[...]

$ while sleep 1; do date; done | grep "" | cat
(no output)
```

This happens because libc will default to line buffered output when stdout is a tty, and fully buffered output otherwise (such as with your pipe to cat). If you wait, it'll still produce the correct output -- it'll just do it in larger batches at a time.

In this case it's due to `grep`, so you can use `--line-buffered`:

```
$ while sleep 1; do date; done | grep --line-buffered "" | cat
Tue Oct 16 14:55:53 PDT 2018
Tue Oct 16 14:55:54 PDT 2018
```

Many others commands have ways to explicitly do this. For those that don't, see [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe) on the Unix&Linux SE for various ways to trick them.